# SIGABRT in malloc_consolidate - Is it possible that __FUNCTION__ to return NULL?

Tags: c++

I'm using the following piece of code for logging on ARM:

```
template <typename T>
MyClass& operator<<(T const& t)
{
    try
    {
        m_buffer << t;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        /* No exceptions */
    }
    return *this;
}
```

used like this:

```
myClass <<__FUNCTION__<< " some string and int" << 5;
```

But once, I have a crash like this (from thousands of tests). Is it possible that `__FUNCTION__` to return NULL (in this case function name length is 20)?

```
Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
    #0  0x3695f46c in *__GI_raise (sig=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:67
67  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
    in ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c
(gdb) bt full
    #0  0x3695f46c in *__GI_raise (sig=6) at   ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:67
        pid = <value optimized out>
        selftid = 1673
        res = <value optimized out>
    #1  0x36964d70 in *__GI_abort () at abort.c:92
        act = {__sigaction_handler = {sa_handler = 0, sa_sigaction = 0}, sa_mask = {__val = {0 <repeats 32 times>}}, sa_flags = 0, sa_restorer = 0}
        sigs = {__val = {32, 0 <repeats 31 times>}}
    #2  0x369a3e4c in __malloc_assert (assertion=<value optimized out>, file=0x36a5f560 "malloc.c", line=<value optimized out>, function=<value optimized out>) at malloc.c:352
    No locals.
    #3  0x369a41c0 in malloc_consolidate (av=0x34781de0) at malloc.c:5345
        fb = <value optimized out>
        maxfb = 0x36a79288
        p = 0x728818
        nextp = 0x6ddec8
        unsorted_bin = 0x36a7928c
        first_unsorted = <value optimized out>
        nextchunk = 0x728ac8
        size = 688
        nextsize = 880297072
        prevsize = <value optimized out>
        bck = <value optimized out>
        fwd = 0xbec
        __func__ = "malloc_consolidate"
    #4  0x369a70d8 in _int_malloc (av=0x36a7925c, bytes=<value optimized out>) at malloc.c:4573
        nb = <value optimized out>
        idx = 1673
        bin = <value optimized out>
        victim = 0x36a78000
        size = <value optimized out>
        victim_index = <value optimized out>
        remainder = <value optimized out>
        remainder_size = <value optimized out>
        block = <value optimized out>
        bit = <value optimized out>
        map = <value optimized out>
        fwd = <value optimized out>
        bck = <value optimized out>
        errstr = <value optimized out>
        __func__ = "_int_malloc"
    #5  0x369a83d4 in _do_malloc (bytes=525) at malloc.c:4011
            ar_ptr = 0x36a7925c
            victim = <value optimized out>
            __func__ = "_do_malloc"
    #6  0x369aa0e8 in *__GI___libc_malloc (bytes=525) at malloc.c:3648
            mem = <value optimized out>
    #7  0x350b1f4c in operator new(unsigned int) () from /lib/libstdc++.so.6
    No symbol table info available.
    #8  0x3508f0e8 in std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) () from /lib/libstdc++.so.6
    No symbol table info available.
    #9  0x3508fa4c in std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned int) () from /lib/libstdc++.so.6
    No symbol table info available.
    #10 0x350905d0 in std::string::reserve(unsigned int) () from /lib/libstdc++.so.6
    No symbol table info available.
    #11 0x35089de4 in std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::overflow(int) () from /lib/libstdc++.so.6
    No symbol table info available.
    #12 0x3508e648 in std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const*, int) () from /lib/libstdc++.so.6
    No symbol table info available.
    #13 0x35087604 in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int) () from /lib/libstdc++.so.6
    No symbol table info available.
    #14 0x35087958 in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) () from /lib/libstdc++.so.6
    No symbol table info available.
    #15 0x350e8974 in MyClass::operator<< <char [21]> (this=0x34782200, t=...) at ...
```

With valgrind I cannot see anything strange.

LE: The following message is printed during abort: `malloc.c:5345: malloc_consolidate: Assertion 'p->fd_nextsize->bk_nextsize == p' failed`

Comment: Why not say `(__FUNCTION__ ? __FUNCTION__ : "CRAZY WEIRD NULL POINTER")` and check?

Comment: What's `m_buffer`? A `stringstream`? If so, which?

Comment: Yes, it is a `std::stringstream`.

Comment: What's the actual crash? What's the error message? What are the first stack frames? We can't tell anything from this other than that you are using a stringstream.

Comment: Is it *always* the same crash?  Or is the only common part of the occasional failure the `new`/`malloc()` or `delete`/`free()`?  If the latter, you have heap corruption *somewhere*.

Answer (score 2):

The GCC documentation clearly states that `__FUNCTION__` gives you the unadorned name of the function you're in. The only way for this to fail is if you're not in a function.

Most likely you have UB elsewhere, but as is vogue nowadays you did not provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and as such it is impossible to help you further with any confidence.

Comment: In fact, it happened only once. I added the full backtrace. For sure, the statement is used in a function. Actually, it crashed during stream creation: <char [21]> seems to be the function length + null terminator. I'm sorry for misleading